# How to apply pagination and sorting with custom list views on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, community, dynamic-visualforce

Pagination and sorting is not working when creating custom list view on visualforce page(using selectlist)

Comment: Hi, you're going to need to add a lot more information here to get some help! For starters, what code do you have so far and how are you trying to do the sorting/pagination?